# How to define docker commit message in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using `Dockerfile` (`docker build`) is an alternative for doing `docker commit` by hand. By using `docker commit`, there is an option named `--message`, which can be used to define commit messages. Commit messages are displayed in `docker history` in a dedicated column called `COMMENT`. My question is: how to define docker commit message in a `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1):

It is well explained in the official docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#examples), here is how you do it:

First, commit a container to a image:

```
$ docker commit --message "Foo bar" 94bde3da7ffa dockertestcommess
```

Then, tag the image to fit the registry address:

```
$ docker tag dockertestcommess spekulant/dockertestcommess
```

And finally push the commited image:

```
$ docker push spekulant/dockertestcommess
```

And my `docker history` shows the message I commited:

```
$ docker history spekulant/dockertestcommess
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d3c3f4e85723        7 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c cat helloworld.txt                   0B                  Foo bar
fec5f399e907        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "cat …   0B
0f0405202b75        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:17e1650f32b894fc…   8B
3fd9065eaf02        3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:093f0723fa46f6cdb…   4.15MB
```

Comment: The OP knows that. The OP wants to know how to provide a commit message per Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

With a `Dockerfile` and `docker build` you create a completely new image. Therefore you do not have any changes that can be commented with a message. It is not possible to define a commit message in a `Dockerfile`.

As the docs point out `docker commit` is more useful for debugging purposes. To create a new image, `docker build` is recommended: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description

This makes sense, as committed images are hard to reproduce, with only a commit message as a hint on the changes. Using only a Dockerfile always leads to a reproducable build.